# Recojer Fecha por Teclado en Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

Hola quería recoger una fecha por teclado y hacer operaciones con ella,

Como podría hacerlo, ya que lo intenté con la librería "datetime" y
después truncando los datos pero me dá incompatibilidad de tipos de dato

Muchas Gracias!

```
from datetime import date 
from datetime import datetime 

fecha = input('Introduca una fecha: ') #22/08/2020 

dia = data[0:2] 
mes = data[3:5] 
ano = data[6:10] 

calcular_fecha = datetime(int(ano), int(mes), int(dia)) 

fecha1 = calcular_fecha + 32 
fecha2 = calcular_fecha + 64 
fecha3 = calcular_fecha + 90 

print(dia + ', ' + mes + ', ' + ano + ', ' + calcular_fecha )
```

Comment: Deberías ser más especifico, y mostrar lo que has intentado (código), hasta ahora

Comment: from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

fecha  = input('Introduca una fecha: ') #22/08/2020

dia = data[0:2]
mes = data[3:5]
ano = data[6:10]

calcular_fecha = datetime(int(ano), int(mes), int(dia))
fecha1 = calcular_fecha  + 32
fecha2 = calcular_fecha  + 64
fecha3 = calcular_fecha  + 90



print(dia + ', ' + mes + ', ' + ano + ', ' + calcular_fecha )

Comment: De momento tengo eso nada más... gracias

Comment: Por lo que se vé no controlas los formatos de entrada. Supones que quien introduce la fecha sabe qué esperas como tal. Pide año, mes y día por separado, validas que estén en los rangos numéricos esperados y luego los pasas al constructor del objeto fecha con el formato que espera.

Comment: @b1nar10 Por favor no lo pongas en los comentarios, edita y añade a tu pregunta.

Comment: @quevedo Aún estoy aprendiendo Python y le di priodidad a que funcione lo que quiero antes de parsear que la fecha introducida sea correcta!

Comment: @Gabitohh Gracias y Perdona, la verdad es que en comentarios no se estienda nada el código.

Comment: Pero, si usas tres input recoges la fecha sin problema y te va a funcionar

Comment: @quevedo sii la puedo recoger sin problema pero al usar la librería “datetime” para sumarle días sobre la fecha que introduzca el usuario, (que es lo que quiero hacer)  y me dá incompatibilidad de tipos....

Comment: si obtienes un timestamp, sumas los días en el rango de magnitud adecuado al timestamp y te devuelves estaría resuelto

Comment: ej: b = datetime.datetime(2020,4,12) / c=b.timestamp()  / d= c + numdias * 2592000.0 / result = b.fromtimestamp(d) No uso datetime.date porque no vi en su `__dir__()` como pasar a timestamp

Comment: Que es lo buscas lograr?